# Как получить данные из файла и вывести их в TextView

Tags: android, файлы, textview

Подскажите, как реализовать. 
Есть текстовый файл,  в нем находится текст песни с расставленными в нужных местах аккордами.
Как получить данные (текст песни с аккордами) из этого файла и вывести их в TextView.
Притом что бы аккорды остались на своих местах, были выделены жирным шрифтом и изменили свой цвет.[image: Пример содержимого текстового файла.]

Comment: Чтобы лучше понять о чём речь, надо бы несколько строк из того файла с аккордами

Comment: легче HTML страницы подгружать в WebView